# Should Key Bindings be Declared inside the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

I couldn't find much information about Java Key Bindings and Thread safety.

I have a segment of code like this:

```
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "leftArrowKey");
        getActionMap().put("leftArrowKey", new LeftArrowListener());

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "rightArrowKey");
        getActionMap().put("rightArrowKey", new RightArrowListener());
```

Should this code always be kept inside the EDT?

Or is it okay to put this on a separate thread?

Comment: I guess if I wanted to ensure thread safety, it'd be best to keep that code in the EDT, but is it still thread-safe if I keep that code in a different thread?

Comment: Any Swing or AWT method whose contract does not specifically state it is safe to call from any thread, should be assumed to require the EDT.  [getInputMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap%28int%29) and [getActionMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap%28%29) have no such provision, so always call them in the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

There are parts of Swing that are *thread hostile*. It is not defined which parts. Therefore, just do everything Swing on the EDT.